# How to make FAB work in Fragment from a Activity and not in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm putting my FAB in a Fragment from an Activity and I keep getting this error:

```
10-01 21:01:55.238 22031-22031/com.vei.scanandgo E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.vei.scanandgo, PID: 22031
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #408: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at com.vei.scanandgo.BaseFragment.storeView(BaseFragment.java:317)
. . .
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
. . .
. ...
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
     at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:159)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
. . 
. ..
```

Gradle is set to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Inflate is done by:

```
View mView = inflater.inflate(getlayoutResId(), container, false);
```

The only thing that I haven't changed is the Activity to AppCompatActivity which will hit a lot of existing codes.
Do we have a way to make this FAB work with Activity?

FAB:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pichere"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Thanks!

If I am making a wrong design, please advise on what else I can do to make this fragment with FAB work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we have a way to make this FAB work with Activity?

Not directly. `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` requires `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat`.

I have a cross-port of that widget in [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport) that works with a regular `Activity` (or `FragmentActivity`), but it is for a `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher, as it requires `Theme.Material`.

There are other FAB implementations, such as [this one](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton), that do not require `appcompat-v7` and do not require `Theme.Material`.