# FAB from github integration issues

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Due to this issue> [How to make FAB work in Fragment from a Activity and not in AppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512732/how-to-make-fab-work-in-fragment-from-a-activity-and-not-in-appcompatactivity/46513034#46513034)

I decided to use this resource > 
https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

But when I put it in my layout 2 problems appear,

> 1. Black background around the FAB
> 2. Redline around the FAB circle.

[image] :

How can I fix this?

**FAB in xml**

```
 <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/smiley"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"` use  `fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/app_primary"`.

```
 <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/app_primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/app_primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/app_ripple"/>
```

I hope it will help you.